# Select a directory to search for existing Android projects Issue while importing Android into Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import

I have an android application that i want to get it imported into ECLIPSE IDE .I am able to select the project folder by navigating through import option of the ECLIPSE.I am even able to see the projects available in the folder still and i can see the Finish button Enabled Click event is not getting happened in Finish Button and so on Project is not getting imported..

Here is the Snapshot of my try ..
[image: Snapshot]

Please help me to resolve this issue..
Thanks..

Comment: You already have same project in your workspace,remove other project from workspace or change your workspace.